# Can a contact directory hold messenger links aka custom mine_types in the lookup entities?

Tags: android, directory, contacts, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I'm working on a custom directory implementation so that you can look up contacts (with the path "contacts/lookup/*/entities") in your caller app from a remote server.

Right now I have working most basic fields like:

- Name (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName)
- Phone numbers (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone)
- Addresses (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal)
- Company data (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization)
- Birthdays (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event)
- Email (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email)
- Websites (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email)

However, I'm struggling to find a way to add social messengers. I have read through the RawContacts from my regular phone entries and figured out the correct values for the MineTypes, AccountTypes, data1, data2 and data3.

Is this simply not possible? I have right now no access to a Google Work profile with sample data to verify if I can see there e.g. Google Meet.

Bonus question: How can I add profile pictures? (Just in case you know it)

Just to understand what I mean, here is a screenshot of my sample data:
[image: Micky Maus]

Here is in red what I'm trying to add:
[image: A sample contact]

Comment: Since I got just 8 views to this question when writing this comment (and I guess 4 were mine) I opened a bug on the [Google Bug-Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/287752862) since this is related to bad documentation.